# Qt Creator: QTableWidget with multiple columns of vertical headers

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

I am using Qt Creator to create a GUI for a simple computer emulator. For memory, I need 100 slots which can contain input from the user. I would like each slot to be linked to the same table; however, I can't seem to figure out a way to split up the table into five numbered columns. As of right now, I have five separate tables to simulate how I would like *one* table to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IYrg.png).

Is it possible to do this with QTableWidget or would I be better off trying my luck with another widget?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a qtablewidget, but you won't be able to use the standard indexing feature. You'll probably have to create your own QAbstractDelegate subclass and have it create widget containing a label with the number (you can access the the modelindex to calculate the number) and a textedit. Then you might even need to figure out what kind of QAbstractItemmodel subclass fits you purpose, etc.

In the end you're probably better off doing it the way you did here. Although I'd suggest using a QListView, which is basically a single-column tableview.